# Crystal Reports Details Section Suppression Blank Section Locked

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, suppression

I am trying to modify a report for a company but the code editor seems to be uneditable. The report has s details section where I want to conditionally suppress rows. When i click on the X-2 editor for the Suppress Blank Rows section the Non Drill Down section's code editor view contains code, but cannot be changed. The background is grey and cannot be changed. Does anyone know how or where to edit the code for this section?